# How do you calculate the duration/length of an mp4 video using php?

Tags: php, mp4

How do you get/calculate the duration/length of an mp4 video with php?

[I tried using this](http://www.tommylacroix.com/2009/06/11/mp4-and-f4v-php-flash-video-meta-data-reader/) but it only works for f4v. :< Can you help me with the mp4 case ?

Comment: google for some command line utility and call it using php

Comment: take a look at http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract duration time from ffmpeg output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239350/how-to-extract-duration-time-from-ffmpeg-output)

Answer (score 4):

I could not get tandu's solution working.

Here's what eventually worked for me:

```
$ffmpeg_output = shell_exec("ffmpeg -i \"$file\" 2>&1");
if( preg_match('/.*Duration: ([0-9:]+).*/', $ffmpeg_output, $matches) ) {
    echo $matches[1];
} else {
    echo "$file failed\n";
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Simple and perfect. Thanks for posting @Henno

Comment: This can result in 0 second durations. As ffmpeg will also return milliseconds. So the output is like this: **00:00:05.66** and the regex above will ignore decimal **00:00:05**. What you need is: `/.*Duration: ((\d+)(?:\:)(\d+)(?:\:)(\d+))*/i`.

Answer (score 2):

I've also wanted to do this recently.  I did a lot of research on it, and there is no native way in php.  One suggestion is [ffmpeg-php](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net), but it did not appear to work for me.  Another method is to use the command line ffmpeg:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i \"{$videofile}\" 2>&1");
$search='/Duration: (.*?),/';
$duration=preg_match($search, $duration, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
```

Comment: I created a php class based on this approach: https://github.com/bfanger/sledgehammer_ffmpeg/blob/master/classes/FFVideo.php

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in pure php by using the [php-reader](https://code.google.com/p/php-reader/) library. This library is a full implementation of the `ISO Base Media File Format, or ISO/IEC 14496-12` in pure php. Then you can either trust the metadata header for the duration, or calculate it yourself based on the stbl boxes.