# How to crop last N seconds from a TS video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

Is there any way to crop the last N seconds from a video? The format is in this case 'MPEG-TS'.

With FFMPEG, I know there is an option for start time and duration, but neither of these are usable in this use case. Video can have any possible length, so the duration cannot be fixed value.

Also, the solution must run in Windows command line and can be automated.

Comment: Are your videos limited to a specific container format? If so, look for the container-specific tools such as avisplit from transcode.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The question should have been "**How to crop last N seconds from a TS video with any command line tool in Windows.**"

Comment: Not too many tools working with TS. Try tsMuxeR: http://www.videohelp.com/tools/tsMuxeR

Comment: Actually it's also OK if I at first convert them to MP4 h264. And then do the cropping. But tsMuxeR looks very good. I will try that!

Comment: ..but the cropping does not support cropping from the end. Only the start and end time for the cropping. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired functionality can be achieved with the following steps:

1. Use **ffmpeg** to determine the length of the video. Use e.g. a cmd script:

   ```
   set input=video.ts

   ffmpeg -i "%input%" 2> output.tmp

   rem search "  Duration: HH:MM:SS.mm, start: NNNN.NNNN, bitrate: xxxx kb/s"
   for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=:., " %%i in (output.tmp) do (
       if "%%i"=="Duration" call :calcLength %%j %%k %%l %%m
   )
   goto :EOF

   :calcLength
   set /A s=%3
   set /A s=s+%2*60
   set /A s=s+%1*60*60
   set /A VIDEO_LENGTH_S = s
   set /A VIDEO_LENGTH_MS = s*1000 + %4
   echo Video duration %1:%2:%3.%4 = %VIDEO_LENGTH_MS%ms = %VIDEO_LENGTH_S%s
   ```
2. Calculate the start and end point for clip operation

   ```
   rem ** 2:00 for the start, 4:00 from the end
   set /A starttime = 120
   set /A stoptime = VIDEO_LENGTH_S - 4*60 
   set /A duration = stoptime - starttime
   ```
3. Clip the video. As a bonus, convert the TS file to a more optimal format, such as H.264

   ```
   set output=video.mp4

   vlc -vvv --start-time %starttime% --stop-time %stoptime% "%input%" 
     --sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1200,acodec=mp3, 
     ab=128}:standard{access=file,dst=%output%} vlc://quit

   rem ** Handbrake has much better quality **
   handbrakeCLI -i %input% -o %output% -e x264 -B 128 -q 25 
     --start-at duration:%starttime% --stop-at duration:%duration%
   ```

Comment: This assumes ffmpeg prints duration for all videos, which still might not be the case.