# Perl Audio file duration

Tags: perl, audio, metadata

I am writing an audio playlist generator. However, I want it to output not only name and numeration in a strict row but also **duration of an audio file**. Is it any way I can do so without such hacks like:

```
print "#: $number\tDuration: ";
system("mp3info -p \"%m:%s\" \"$track\"");
print "\tNAME: $name";
```

If it is any important, my perl version is `v5.16.3`.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the MP3::Info module?  https://metacpan.org/pod/MP3::Info

Comment: @TrentonTrama I'm afraid it works only for mp3, not for other audio formats. To be more precise, I need only mp3 and flac.

Comment: If you only need those two formats,  you can use a combination of MP3::Info and Audio::FLAC::Decoder or Audio::FLAC::Header.  
Decoder has a `time_total` function that returns the total number of seconds.  
Header returns a hash that contains the time segments of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you want to determine the file type based on the file content instead of the extension, `File::Type` comes in handy for this. MP3::Info and Audio::Flac::Header are well written perl modules.

```
use File::Type;
use MP3::Info;
use Audio::FLAC::Header;

my $duration = -1;
my $ft = File::Type->new()->checktype_filename($track);

$duration = Audio::FLAC::Header
              ->new($track)
              ->tags()
              ->{trackTotalLengthSeconds} 
              if($ft eq 'audio/flac');

$duration = MP3::Info
              ->get_mp3info($track)
              ->{SECS} 
              if($ft eq 'audio/mpeg3');
```

Comment: is it possible to use some universal method instead of including different modules with different methods?

Comment: You could use a library such as libavcodec - the engine behind ffmpeg. This knows about different files types, but the core engine is in c. [Video::FFmpeg](http://search.cpan.org/~randomman/Video-FFmpeg-0.47/lib/Video/FFmpeg.pm) may do what you want.

Comment: I will answer as soon as I overcome errors in installing FFmpeg modules.

Comment: In my case i used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239350/how-to-extract-duration-time-from-ffmpeg-output with `my $duration = \`ffmpeg -i \"$track\" 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk '{print \$2;}' | tr -d ,\`;`