# How can I get the thumbnail of the middle of my video with NReco.VideoConverter (or another library)?

Tags: c#, video, thumbnails

I want to get the thumbnail of the middle of my video with NReco.VideoConverter.
This is my code:

```
var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(videoPath, thumbnailPath);
```

But I can only get the thumbnail of the first frame.

Any idea? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Frames can be extracted from anywhere within the video by using the overloaded GetVideoThumbnail method:

```
GetVideoThumbnail(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath, Nullable<Single> frameTime)
```

where frameTime is the video position (in seconds) as described in the API documentation: [FFMpegConverter.GetVideoThumbnail Method (String, String, Nullable<Single>)](http://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.VideoConverter/?topic=html/M_NReco_VideoConverter_FFMpegConverter_GetVideoThumbnail_3.htm)

So to extract the frame 1 second into a video called TestVideo.mp4, you would use:

```
FFMpegConverter ffmpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
ffmpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(@"C:\TestVideo.mp4", @"C:\ExtractedFrame.jpeg", 1.0f);
```

To literally extract the middle frame is a bit more involved as you need to find the total video length first. This can be done by using ffprobe (found in the FFmpeg download, see [ffmpeg.org](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)). With the help of [How to extract duration time from ffmpeg output?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22243834) and [How to spawn a process and capture its STDOUT in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/285841) we can setup a process to run ffprobe and parse the duration string to a float as follows:

```
public void ExtractMiddleFrame()
{
    float duration = GetVideoDuration();

    FFMpegConverter ffmpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
    ffmpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(@"C:\TestVideo.mp4", @"C:\ExtractedFrame.jpeg", duration/2.0f);
}

private float GetVideoDuration()
{
    float duration = 0.0f;

    Process ffprobe = new Process();
    ffprobe.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\ffmpeg-20150606-git-f073764-win32-static\bin\ffprobe.exe";
    ffprobe.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-i {0} -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv=\"p=0\"", @"C:\TestVideo.mp4");
    ffprobe.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    ffprobe.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    ffprobe.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Data != null)
            duration = ParseDurationString(args.Data);
    };

    ffprobe.Start();
    ffprobe.BeginOutputReadLine();
    ffprobe.WaitForExit();

    return duration;
}

private float ParseDurationString(string durationString)
{
    float duration = 0.0f;
    if (float.TryParse(durationString, out duration) == false)
        throw new Exception("Could not parse duration string.");
    return duration;
}
```

Comment: I downloaded the ffprobe from here: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/, and it doesn't work, it returns 0 for the duration. I used the same code you provided

Comment: Sorry, it works like a charm! My mistake was to use a file with spaces. Thanks dude!