# Video duration time FFMpeg PHP

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

This is probably a dumb question, im trying to get the duration from a video using FFMpeg:  `Video Duration Time = 1m:47s`

**My function**

```
$ffmpeg = \FFMpeg\FFProbe::create();
$duration = $ffmpeg->format($videos[0]->real_path)->get('duration');
```

Now if i print **$duration** : `"109.713333"`

How can i get the video duration time from `$duration`??

Note:

I Tried this

```
 109.713333 / 60 = 1.82 
 82/60 = 1.36 and 82-36 = 46
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract duration time from ffmpeg output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239350/how-to-extract-duration-time-from-ffmpeg-output)

Answer (score 1):

If you still need it try :

```
$totalSecs = $ffmpeg->format($videos[0]->real_path)->get('duration');
$tempSecs['s'] = $totalSecs;
$duration = gmdate("H:i:s", (int)$tempSecs['s']);

echo "video duration : " . $duration;
```

PS : 
Where is this `Duration Time = 1m:47s` amount coming from?
**109** seconds should give 1 minute and **49** secs. Think about it. So this means one of your feedbacks is wrong...